# Connect to remote kafka from command within docker container

Tags: apache-kafka

We tried to connect to kafka using below command however we are not able to reach the broker. Could anyone help us here.

```
sudo docker run --rm --name=jaeger1 -e SPAN_STORAGE_TYPE=kafka -p 14267:14267/tcp -p 14268:14268/tcp -p 9411:9411/tcp jaegertracing/jaeger-collector --kafka.producer.topic="test Span" --kafka.producer.brokers=<broker>:9092 --kafka.producer.plaintext.password="" --kafka.producer.plaintext.username="<username>"
```

```
{"level":"fatal","ts":1585232844.0954845,"caller":"collector/main.go:70","msg":"Failed to init storage factory","error":"kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to (Is your cluster reachable?)"
```

Please let us know what we are missing.

Comment: where is Kafka running? Also Docker? elsewhere?

Comment: Thanks Robin for reply .Not in docker in some host..

Comment: The error message you've got `Is your cluster reachable` suggests you've got a problem with you connectivity. Is Kafka running on a local instance? Cloud? VM? Can you run a producer/consumer on your local machine successfully connecting to it?

Comment: The answer is still the same if Kafka is running in Docker on another host. The problem isn't even docker here. Can you connect to `<broker>:9092` **outside Docker**?

Comment: YEA I am able to access kafka outside dcker and docker Image Im using is "jaegertracing/jaeger-collector"